# What is a proper replacement of paper-menu and paper-submenu in Polymer 3?

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x

I have a polymer 1 application that used paper-menu and paper-submenu.  I am rewriting it in Polymer 3.  What is the general consensus for its replacement? I have searched for this and have found nothing.  It would be good if the documentation for paper-menu and paper-submenu showed its replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced paper-menu and paper-submenu with the Polymer 3 elements [vaadin-accordion](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-accordion) and [paper-listbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@polymer/paper-listbox)

```
          <vaadin-accordion>
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{sources}}">
              <vaadin-accordion-panel theme="filled">
                <div slot="summary">[[item.name]]</div>
                <paper-listbox>
                  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{item.models}}">
                    <paper-item on-tap="selectModel">[[item.name]]</paper-item>
                  </template>
                </paper-listbox>
              </vaadin-accordion-panel>
            </template>
          </vaadin-accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer MWC-Menu for polymer 3 support [link here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-components/blob/master/demos/menu.html)